# What is the flaw in this proof on countability of $\mathbf{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

The book `Understanding Analysis` by Stephen Abbott asks to find a flaw in the following proof regarding countability of rational numbers. I would like to know, if my argument is correct.

> Review the proof of the uncountability of real numbers, and then find a flaw in the erroneous proof that $\mathbf{Q}$ is uncountable.
>
> ***Proof.***
>
> Assume, for contradiction that $\mathbf{Q}$ is countable. Thus, we can write $\mathbf{Q} = \{r_1,r_2,r_3,\ldots \}$ and as before, construct a nested sequence of closed intervals with $r_n \notin I_n$. Our construction implies $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n = \phi$, while NIP implies that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n \neq \phi$. This contradiction implies that $\mathbf{Q}$ must therefore be uncountable.

**My argument.**

*Statement of NIP*.

Intuitively, the nested interval property says that, if we take smaller and smaller subsets of the real line, and do this an infinitely large number of times, we still end up with a number $x \in \mathbf{R}$.  There are no holes in $\mathbf{R}$.

Suppose $I_n = [a_n,b_n] = \{x \in \mathbf{R}:a_n \le x \le b_n\}$ is a closed interval in $\mathbf{R}$. And assume that $I_{n+1} \subseteq I_n$. Then the resulting sequence of nested intervals :

\begin{align}
I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq I_3 \supseteq \ldots \supseteq I_n \supseteq I_{n+1} \supseteq \ldots
\end{align}

has a non-empty intersection, that is

\begin{align}
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n \neq \phi
\end{align}

Any such interval $I_n = [a_n,b_n]$ cannot be constructed out of rational numbers alone. In fact, it will have rationals and a large proportion of irrationals. NIP is therefore valid for real numbers alone. $\mathbf{Q}$ is not complete and does not satisfy the AoC (axiom of completeness).

Comment: Well, on the one hand I think it would suffice to simply say that, as stated, the Theorem you cite only applies to the reals...in particular, it produces a real number, not a rational number.  However, I think your argument would have more force if you showed that, in fact, it is possible to construct an infinite family of nested  non-empty closed intervals of rationals which has empty intersection.

Comment: @lulu, a concrete example would be something like: Define $I_n = \{q \in \mathbf{Q}: 2-\frac{1}{2^n} < q^2 < 2 + \frac{1}{2^n}\}$. Each $I_n \supseteq I_{n+1}$. And, their infinite intersection is empty. Am I correct?

Comment: You need closed intervals.  But if $L_1<L_2<\cdots$ converges to $\sqrt 2$ from the left and $R_1>R_2>\cdots$ converges to $\sqrt 2$ from the right then the intervals $[L_i, R_i]$ suffice.

Comment: Is $\phi$ (phi) supposed to be the empty set?

Comment: @alex, yeah phi is supposed to mean the empty set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are these intervals?

Are they intervals in $\Bbb R$? Then $\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty I_n=\varnothing$ is not something we can conclude from the construction, only $\Bbb Q\cap \bigcap_{n=0}^\infty I_n=\varnothing$.

Are they intervals in $\Bbb Q$? Then the NIP doesn't apply.

Comment: I was trying to argue the latter: NIP does not apply to intervals in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Quasar That's easy: Read the exact wording of NIP, and it will tell you exactly when it applies. Your situation (the $I_n$ being intervals of $\Bbb Q$) is not one of them. That's all.